# Level curves of a surface

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw level curves f(x,y)=0; f(x,y)=10; f(x,y)=25, of the two variable graph f(x,y)=-50+x^2+y^2.
This is what I have done

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[]
        \addplot3[domain=-5:5,surf] {(-50+x*x+y*y)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add some more `\addplot3`s with the needed curves. In this case I prefer to use polar coordinates, and I changed your `surf` for a `mesh` because I think it's better for visibility. Of course, you can revert it if you want.

For example, with this code

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot3[domain=-10:10,mesh] {(-50+x*x+y*y)};
  \foreach\z in{0,10,25}
    \addplot3[thick,green!50!black,domain=0:360,samples=73]
      ({sqrt(\z+50)*cos(\x)},{sqrt(\z+50)*sin(\x)},\z);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you'll get
[image]

Comment: I tried the code but it is showing some error

Comment: @InspireMaths, it works fine in my computer. What error do you get? Could be the pgfplots version?